# In flutter app is there any way to open Settings>Privacy>Ads page from our Own application?

Tags: flutter, ads, privacy, system-setting, maid

I want to open Settings>Privacy>Ads page on Butten click.

Is there any way to open Global privacy ads settings from out app.Need to open particular page and do some action on settings page.Currently i can open settings page but show page inside Privacy.